# c# List inside list XML Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following statement

```
xdoc.Descendants("Father").Select(p => new
    {
        Son1 = (string)p.Element("Son1").Value,
        Son2 = (string)p.Element("Son2").Value,
        Son3= (string)p.Element("Son3").Value,
        Son4 = (string)p.Element("Son4").Value,
        Son5 = (string)p.Element("Son5").Value

    }).ToList().ForEach(p =>
    {

        Response.Write("Son1= " + p.Son1 + "  ");
        Response.Write("Son2=" + p.Son2 + "  ");
        Response.Write("Son3=" + p.Son3 + "  ");
        Response.Write(("Son4 =") + p.Son4 + "  ");
        Response.Write(("Son5 =") + p.Son5 + "  ");
        Response.Write("<br />");
    });
```

and it works fine as long as i have only one instance of each son , the problem is that i have multiple instances of Son5, and i don´t know how to put Son5 inside of a list

Here is my XML code Example:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have several elements of same type, then you should parse them to list or other collection:

```
var fathers = from f in xdoc.Descendants("Father")
              select new {
                Son1 = (string)f.Element("Son1"),
                Son2 = (string)f.Element("Son2"),
                Son3= (string)f.Element("Son3"),
                Son4 = (string)f.Element("Son4"),
                Son5 = f.Elements("Son5").Select(s5 => (string)s5).ToList()
             };
```

Some notes:

- Don't use `.Value` of `XElement` or `XAttribute` - you can cast element itself to appropriate data type without accessing its value. Benefits - less code, more reliable in case element is missing (you will not get NullReferenceException)
- Consider to use `int` or `int?` as elemenent values if your elements contain integer values
- If you have single `Father` element, then don't work with collection of fathers. Just get xml root and check whether it's null or not. After that you can create single `father` object.

Writing response

```
foreach(var father in fathers)
{
     Response.Write($"Son1={father.Son1}  ");
     Response.Write($"Son2={father.Son2}  ");
     Response.Write($"Son3={father.Son3}  ");
     Response.Write($"Son4={father.Son4}  ");     
     Response.Write(String.Join("  ", father.Son5.Select(son5 => $"Son5={son5}"));    
     Response.Write("<br />");  
}
```

Comment: @EvgenySdvizhkov also note that usually you should not write strings directly to response. Consider to create view for your action and use razor syntax to display father data

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
xdoc.Descendants("Father").Select(p => new
{
    Son1 = p.Element("Son1").Value,
    Son2 = p.Element("Son2").Value,
    Son3= p.Element("Son3").Value,
    Son4 = p.Element("Son4").Value,
    Sons5 = p.Elements("Son5").Select(element => element.Value).ToList()

}).ToList().ForEach(p =>
{

    Response.Write("Son1= " + p.Son1 + "  ");
    Response.Write("Son2=" + p.Son2 + "  ");
    Response.Write("Son3=" + p.Son3 + "  ");
    Response.Write("Son4 =" + p.Son4 + "  ");
    p.Sons5.ForEach(son5 => Response.Write("Son5 =" + son5 + "  "));
    Response.Write("<br />");
});
```

That will create a list of `Son5` within your list of items, which you can iterate in the `ForEach` with another `ForEach`.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: Corrected the post. Actually none of the casts is necessary